# Unable to find / click on xlink:href in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ember.js

Good morning,

I am running into an issue with Selenium where it can not see a button that I am trying to click. 
Here is what the element looks like:

```
<a data-ember-action="792" href="#"></a>
```

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="margin-top:8px; margin-left:16px;" width="16" height="16">
    <image alt="Edit product" xlink:href="/assets/images/edit.f65eeadf.svg" width="16" height="16" y="0" x="0" style="margin-top:8px; margin-left:16px;"></image>
</svg>
```

I have tried the following in order to find the element:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//image[contains(@src,'/assets/images/edit.f65eeadf.svg')]/parent::a").click()
```

and:

```
edit_icon_button = wd.find_element_by_partial_link_text("f65eeadf.svg")
edit_icon_button.click()
```

and:

```
edit_product_icon = wd.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt='Edit product'][src*='/assets/images/edit.f65eeadf.svg'")
edit_product_icon.click()
```

Nothing I have tried seems to work.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to find this element on the page?

Thank you.

Comment: What exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason is because `svg` and `image` elements are embedded within a link.
For example, when you try to find by css `"img[alt='Edit Product']"` there are two mistakes here.

1. Selector should be `image`, not `img` - `"image[alt='Edit Product']"`
2. Button you are trying to click is a second parent, so in a pure jQuery you'd do something like:

   ```
   $("image[alt='Edit product']").parents('a').click()
   ```

Not really familiar with other ways to do it in Selenium, but at least you can do:

```
.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

to get to the `a` element you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar issue. Unable to find the Xpath for the download button.
i tried multiple ways to find the Xpath but was not successful. i took the help of XPATH Helper tool to check if the path is correct but all the time what i get is a NULL value. [This is where the highlighter takes me when i hover over the download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWxMK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32138873)